# GameCih: How does it manipulate values?

Tags: android, android-memory, cheat-engine

Some time ago I found this app called "GameCih" which lets you modify values of some of your games.
Now I was wondering - like the title is already saying - how this app gets access to the mobile's memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not developed anything like GameCih, but I do know a little bit on how it works.

Explanation :

[Scanning and Editing Android App Memory Values Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852672/scanning-and-editing-android-app-memory-values-programmatically)

Basically it is more towards assembly language, flag controls, etc on the memory in Android with NDK, so that you could use native languages like C++ to modify / read / write .